# Writing a VAR(1) with ARCH(1) errors as a bilinear model?

Tags: garch, volatility-forecasting

I have been reading a paper and found this quote?

> "Note that a linear conditional mean model with ARCH disturbances can
>   be described by a nonlinear specification without ARCH, i.e. the
>   bilinear model."

How would I actually go about writing the bilinear model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general bilinear model $BL(p, q, r, s)$ can be written as

$$
X_t - \sum_j^p \phi_j X_{t-j}=\varepsilon_{t}+\sum_j^p \theta_i \varepsilon_{t-i} + \sum_k^r \sum_{k'}^s b_{k,k'}X_{t-k}\varepsilon_{t-k'}
$$

where the sequence of $\varepsilon$'s is i.i.d with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$

For the model motivation, properties and derivation please check [this](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching673/chapter4.pdf).